# Read XML Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am actually trying to read this piece of XML.

http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/351352?res=3hourly&key=99b9f578-ad3d-446c-9d29-0bbee028b483

I was wondering how I could read only the node Period with the value="2012-11-15Z"

So the one below :

This is the code I use

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/351352?res=3hourly&key=99b9f578-ad3d-446c-9d29-0bbee028b483"))
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                && reader.Name == "Period")
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                        reader.Name == "Rep")
                    {
                        first.Text = reader.GetAttribute("T");
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

What is the way for me to read only this node ?

Should I write

`if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                && reader.Name == "Period" && reader.GetAttribute("value") == "2012-11-15Z")`

This doesn't seem to work ..

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var period = xdoc.Descendants("Period")
                 .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("value") == "2012-11-15Z") 
                 .SingleOrDefault();
```

It will return XElement, but you can select any data from period. E.g. `T` attributes:

```
List<int> tList = xdoc.Descendants("Period")
                      .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("value") == "2012-11-15Z")
                      .SelectMany(p => p.Elements())
                      .Select(rep => (int)rep.Attribute("T"))
                      .ToList();

var query = xdoc.Descendants("Period")
                .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("value") == "2012-11-15Z")
                .SelectMany(p => p.Elements())
                .Select(rep => new { 
                      T = (int)rep.Attribute("T"),
                      D = (string)rep.Attribute("D") })
                .ToList();
```

Last query will return List of strongly-typed anonymous objects with integer property `T` and string property `D`:

```
 foreach(var x in query)
     // use x.T and x.D
```

Comment: How would I get the attribute "T" then ? Because this is returning all the values like 360   570    720 etc .

Comment: @Demipouce see updated answer. It will return `List<int>` containing values of `T` attribute of all `Rep` elements in selected period. *BTW* seems xpath to be slower http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/12/04/LINQ-to-XML-and-LINQ-to-XML-with-XPath-performance-review.aspx

Comment: Allright ! I see , sorry I just got a bit confused during a moment about these attributes ..
So it returns me a list I can use as a normal list ?

Comment: @Demipouce exactly, it returns usual strongly-typed list of integers. I can even change `var` to exact type. Hold on

Comment: How would I be able to make a double selection of attribute. Do i have to use an array ? and duplicate the .Select(rep => (int)rep.Attribute("T")) for another attribute ?

Comment: @Demipouce see update. Same way you can add any other attributes to result object. Consider reading something about LINQ 2 XML: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath to lookup the value like this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/351352?res=3hourly&key=99b9f578-ad3d-446c-9d29-0bbee028b483"))
{
    doc.Load(reader);
    XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//Period[@value='2012-11-15Z']");
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
}
```